# Representation of non zero rational number

Tags: prime-numbers, arithmetic, rational-numbers

I have seen the following representation of non zero rational numbers in course notes :

$$
\forall r\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\},\quad r = p^{k}\frac{m}{n}\quad k,m,n\in\mathbb{Z}
$$

where $p$ is a prime number not dividing $m$ nor $n$. Where does it come from please ? I would like to know more on this (never studied arithmetic) but unable to find a ressource on this.

Thank you !

Comment: By definition of $\Bbb Q,$ $r=\frac ab$ for some $a\in\Bbb Z$ and $b\in\Bbb N,$ and if you choose some prime $p,$ you can isolate its powers in $a$ and $b:$
$a=mp^i,b=np^j$ with $m\in\Bbb Z$ and $n\in\Bbb N$ both not divisible by $p,$ and integers $i,j\ge0.$ Finally, set $k=i-j.$ But you need to correct your statement: $p$ is a prime number not *dividing* $m$ nor $n.$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you for this comment ! Yes my statement was not correct I modified this ! Oh okay, and why are we sure that we can have the same $p$ in both representation of $a$ and $b$ ? Is this because we can always make appear the same $p$ using the fact $p^{0} = 1$ or I'm wrong ?

Comment: @lhf Thank you ! It makes things more clearer !

Comment: Yes, you choose $p$ first (whatever $a,b$ are), and then "make it appear" in both $a$ and $b$, "using $p^0=1$" when it does not really "appear". For instance if $r=\frac56$ and if you choose $p=2,$ then $m=5,n=3,k=i-j=0-1=-1.$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_valuation